# Create default instance of type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

What is the reflective equivalent of :

```
default(object);  //null
```

When I do not have the type until runtime, e.g.

```
public void Method(Type type)
{
   var instance = type.CreateDefault(); //no such method exists, but I expect there is a way of doing this?
}
```

Answer (score 17):

For any reference type, the default value is a null instance. For any value type, the default value can be obtained via `Activator.CreateInstance`. But when you have a variable called `instance` that suggests you want an *actual instance* rather than a null reference... So while you *can* do this:

```
public object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
}
```

... it's not really clear how useful this is. The is the default *value* of the type, which isn't the same as a default *instance* of the type.

Comment: no, I'm happy with null in this case.  So I'll use Activator for the value types, otherwise null.  Thanks Jon.