# In C# can I cast from a T to at T : new()

Tags: c#, generics

Here's my code:

```
void DoSomething<T>()
{
    var constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(null);

    if(constructor != null)
    {
        DoSomethingElse<T>(); // compiler error
    }
    else
    {
        //...   
    }

}

void DoSomethingElse<T>() where T:new()
{
   T x = new T();
   //...
}
```

Is there a way to convince the compiler that T is a legitimate T:new()?

Comment: well, no. obviously, the compiler doesn't work that way :) you need to add `new()` constraint to your first method as well.

Comment: Can't. DoSomething needs to work with all types, not just ones that have a default constructor.

Comment: hmm then you can try calling `DoSomethingElse` using reflection.

Comment: Does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351385/create-default-instance-of-type

Comment: There is also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529611/c-sharp-create-new-t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to convince compiler other than adding a `new()` constraint, if you can't do that the only way is to go with `Reflection`:

```
var methodType = // get the type of DoSomethingElse here
var genericMethod = methodType.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

// pass instance instead of null if this is an instance method
genericMethod.Invoke(null);
```